# Why is VBA changing decimal to comma automatically?

Tags: excel, vba, locale, decimal-point

I have an Excel macro in VBA. Yesterday everything worked fine, this morning VBA is changing a decimal point to a comma. That is from 5.1 to 5,1.

I am using a German system and have set in Excel's advanced options that a point is a decimal and comma is thousands.

For example I have a value for daily scrum meeting in the Excel sheet set at 3.75

Excel sheet input:
[image: screenshot]

When I use a function to read in the value such as:

```
Sub TestFunction()
    MsgBox (Sheets("Input_Parameters").Cells(25, 2))
End Sub
```

I get the value with commas.

VBA function output:
[image: output]

Is there a setting in the VBA environment to fix this or is there something I am missing. All my backups of the macros are showing the same affect so I know it is nothing I have changed in the code in today's version.

Comment: What do you mean with "*VBA is taking a decimal point and changing the point to a comma.*"? In VBA you can only use the point as decimal `a = 5.3` even in German systems. Can you show your code please ([edit] the question and add it)?

Comment: I know this is a strange issue. It happens on multiple lines when calling out a cell. For example 
SpNum = (Sheets("Input_Parameters").Cells(TargVerFirstRow + i, 4))
in the excel cell is 29.29 but in the vba code and out put I get 29,2857....

Comment: Please don't use comments to add code use the [edit] button to edit your question. Add a *full example* and describe what your code actually does and what you expect it to do. No one can help if you post a single cryptic line of code without any explanation. Also add screenshots to show whats going wrong if this helps you to explain. Your question is very unclear.

Comment: Try `MsgBox Sheets("Input_Parameters").Cells(25, 2).Value` (without the extra parentheses)

Comment: Didn't work still getting the same result

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a normal behavior on German systems with German default locale Windows settings (comma as decimal separator and point as thousand separator in Windows settings).

```
MsgBox .Cells(25, 2).Value
```

returns the value with the format of the Windows locale default.

The `Application.DecimalSeparator` that you set in your Excel options affects what is displayed in the cell, but not what is displayed by message boxes.

Therefore you can use

```
MsgBox .Cells(25, 2).Text
```

which returns the value as text formatted like in the cell.

---

Another workaround is to replace the commas with `replace()` function:

```
MsgBox Replace(.Cells(25, 2).Value, ",", ".")
```

Comment: This was indeed the issue. Pushing the value out as a string converted the point to comma. In the end the value is write but the comma should be a point. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One of the first functions I have created, after I came to Germany was this one:

```
Public Function ChangeCommas(ByVal myValue As Variant) As String

    Dim temp As String
    temp = CStr(myValue)
    ChangeCommas = Replace(temp, ",", ".")

End Function
```

Since the last 2 years it is present in every VBA project.