# VBA Replace dot with comma

Tags: vba, excel

I have just started developing macros with VBA. I have some trouble replacing dots with commas using my macro

I tried these codes :

```
Dim Cell As Range

For Each Cell In Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))
  Cell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Cell.Value, ".", ",")
Next
```

And This one

```
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)).Select
Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:=",", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

But both give wrong result. For example for 124.419022 it gives 124 419 022
instead of 124.419022

Can anyone please help me find a solution for this problem ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe you need to do that through Regional Settings in Windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA changing decimal to comma automaticaly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43863482/vba-changing-decimal-to-comma-automaticaly)

Comment: You need to format the cell's as text for this to work. Otherwise regional formats takes over.

Comment: Just change the .NumberFormat property.

Comment: You're working against the value. You could just change to `Cell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Cell.Text, ".", ",")` However if you're actually using the values, you'll run into numbers stored as text and that kind of errors, as well as unexpected numberformatting settings.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
With Application
.DecimalSeparator = ","
.UseSystemSeparators = True
End With
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
With Application
.DecimalSeparator = "."
.UseSystemSeparators = False
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.